# JavaScript Settings - What are these called?

Tags: javascript, settings

I feel silly asking this but what are these called? Please see the highlighted portion in the screenshot. Thank you!

[image: JavaScript Settings Image Link]

Comment: It's extremely common to use plain JavaScript objects for settings/options APIs. They're just objects.

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators). This is basic syntax.

Comment: @Pointy, I apologize for the duplicate question. I didn't know what to ask or look for. Now I know!

Comment: When an object is used as a parameter to a widget like this, they're usually called **options**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are "properties" of a JavaScript object.

You can read up on objects here: [MDN - Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score -1):

These are properties of a JSON object

Comment: Well no, those are *JavaScript* objects. JSON is an encoding format for object-structured data.

Comment: The arrow on the image that Peter provided points to the properties of a JSON object ( height, width e.t.c, these are called properties and not a javascript object. The javascript object is the object that holds all these properties including the { } braces.

Comment: @gijoe Pointy isn't arguing that they aren't properties. He's arguing that the thing the properties are contained in is called a JavaScript object rather than a JSON object.

Comment: Yes, those are properties of an object, but no, this is not a JSON object. I know this because [There’s no such thing as a “JSON Object”](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Yes Xufox, you re right its more correct to call it just an Object

Comment: JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation" and is a way of storing data in text using name-value pairs. It was originally derived from the JavaScript syntax and is similar but not the same thing. JSON is an open-standard file format. Edit- one way to quickly tell a JSON string from a JavaScript object is that in JSON the keys must be strings wrapped in quotes, i.e. `{"color": "blue"}